# Push View Controller on Remote Notification's 'Default User Action' in Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have setup Remote Notifications and added a few custom keys to the payload that will give the option to push a specific detail ViewController on the home page if the user taps the notification and wants to read more about that topic.

*For example*: `linkType: "services"` and `linkPost: "main"` would tell my app to push the main services page when the app comes to the foreground.

I can successfully access the keys and values in my variables `topicValue`, `linkType`, and `linkPost` but I'm having trouble debugging the path the code takes when the user taps the notification so I know where and when to push the correct ViewController. I'm using the Xamarin.Essentials packages so I can `Get` and `Set` these key value pairs. I can access them anywhere throughout the app.

```
public class MyNotificationCenterDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
{
    public override void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, Action completionHandler)
    {
        if (response.IsDefaultAction)
        {
            var userInfo = response.Notification.Request.Content.UserInfo;

            string topicValue = userInfo.ObjectForKey(new NSString("topic")).ToString();
            string linkType = userInfo.ObjectForKey(new NSString("linktype")).ToString();
            string linkPost = userInfo.ObjectForKey(new NSString("linkpage")).ToString();
            Preferences.Set("linkType", linkType);
            Preferences.Set("linkPost", linkPost);
```

I originally tried using the `launchOptions` parameter within the `FinishedLaunching` method in the AppDelegate but when I set breakpoints they don't seem to hit when I tap the remote notification. Any help accomplishing this in Xamarin.iOS would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

**Two things (Background state or InActive state)**

- If your app is not available in the background and you work with notification then you should use `DidFinishLaunching`
  For this situation, you should set the key of which is comes from the notification. And you will get that key from launchOptions.
  Compare that key in `viewWillAppear` of `HomeViewController` and put `RedirectScreen` code if key match.

  Ex:- `linkType: "services"`
- If your app is available in the background and notification comes then DidReceiveNotificationResponse call and you can redirect any of the screens in your app.
  For this first, you should fetch `topMostViewController` then use this controller for the redirect to any screen.

Ex:- To get `topMostViewController`

```
    public static UIViewController GetTopViewController()
{
    var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
    var vc = window.RootViewController;
    while (vc.PresentedViewController != null)
        vc = vc.PresentedViewController;

    if (vc is UINavigationController navController)
        vc = navController.ViewControllers.Last();

    return vc;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nilesh! That helped solve the issue in `DidReceiveNotificationResponse` when the app is in the background. My app still crashes when user taps the notification when app is inactive. I'm using Microsoft App Center to check crash logs since debug mode stops in VS for Mac when you close out the app to test. The app is crashing in the `DidReceiveNotificationResponse` method! So on my device with iOS12 `DidReceiveNotificationResponse` is also being called when app is inactive. It's tough to debug this without being able to use breakpoints so I'll update the thread as I find out more.

Comment: The app is crashing more specifically within the conditional logic `if (response.IsDefaultAction)` within `DidReceiveNotificationResponse` when the app is in inactive state. That conditional logic is where I choose which detail view controller to push onto the Home NavigationController or to select a particular TabBarController index to navigate the user. I'm assuming my window, or tabcontroller or all of it is null since the app is coming from inactive state instead of background state ... now to figure it all out without debugging and breakpoints ...

Comment: Crash, because when app in an inactive status than no topmost controller found , the solution is check status != Inactive is did receive remote notification so when app comes from inactive statue that time app will not crash.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution to my particular use case. Thank you again Nilesh for helping me arrive here :)

```
public class MyNotificationCenterDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
{
    UIViewController detailViewController;
    public override void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, Action completionHandler)
    {
        UIApplication application = UIApplication.SharedApplication;
        if (response.IsDefaultAction)
        {
            var userInfo = response.Notification.Request.Content.UserInfo;

            string linkType = userInfo.ObjectForKey(new NSString("linktype")).ToString();
            string linkPost = userInfo.ObjectForKey(new NSString("linkpage")).ToString();

//I'm using Xamarin.Essentials package to manage my User Defaults Key Value pairs with the
// Preferences method. Then I can see if those keys are set or not in ViewDidLoad in 
// my HomeViewController. This covers the case if the app had been closed 
//when the notification is tapped.

            Preferences.Set("linkType", linkType);
            Preferences.Set("linkPost", linkPost);

            var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
            var tc = window.RootViewController as UITabBarController;

            if(tc != null) 
            {
//this is essential. if app was in background then `tc != null` and this logic can run here.
//If the app was closed and `tc == null` then this logic will be carried out at the end of my 
// ViewDidLoad method in my HomeViewController instead of this method.

// carry out your logic for your app to either push a view controller or
// select a TabBarController index ...

//if you are pushing a detail view controller on your Home Navigation Controller
              var homeNavController = tc.ChildViewControllers[0] as UINavigationController;
              homeNavController.PushViewController(detailViewController, true);

              tc.SelectedIndex = 0; //select my HomeViewController via TabBarController index
//HomeViewController is where I'm pushing the detail controller so I want to make to navigate in case the user backgrounded the app on another TabBarController index.
            }
      }

   completionHandler();
}
```

So in addition to this I needed to carry out the same navigation logic (choosing which view controller to push or which TabBarController index to select) at the end of my `ViewDidLoad` method in my `HomeViewController`. You access the Preferences keys you set to choose where to navigate. This covers the case of the app being closed when the user taps on the notification.

Hope this helps somebody else trying to accomplish this type of 'deep linking' with their remote notification in Xamarin.iOS!